# Netflix White Sceen or Black Screen Ubuntu 12.04 Need Answers

Tags: netflix

Problems with Netflix-App after install. I get a white or black screen. The show is apparently running with no video. Followed all the automatic procedures for install. Looking for an update, patch, fix or a link to one of these please.

I have tried a few things listed on other posts but have not found a solution.